# Show that a map is a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry

Please note: I am still a beginner in differential geometry.

Let $\psi: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash\{0\} \mapsto S^n, x \mapsto \frac{x}{||x||}$. Show that $\psi$ is a submersion.

The definition I have of submersion is the following: if $M, N$ are smooth manifolds, a map $F:M\mapsto N$  is a submersion if and only if its pushforward $F_{*_p}$ is surjective at every point $p \in M$, that is, $rank(F) = dim(N)$. The rank of a map is the rank of the jacobian matrix of said map.

It's not difficult to compute the jacobian matrix. One has
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{x_i}{||x||}= \frac{x_1^2+\dots+x_{i-1}^2+x_{i+1}^2+\dots+x_n^2}{(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{x_j}{||x||}= \frac{- x_i x_j}{(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{equation*}

How do I go on from here? How do I compute the rank of the resulting matrix? Is this the correct method at all?

Comment: Do you mean $S^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. $\psi: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash\{0\} \mapsto S^n$. Edited.

Comment: While your approach works, I think it's worth noting that, in general, the "jacobian matrix" of a map between manifolds $F:M \to N$ is not well-defined. One can speak of the jacobian matrix of the coordinate chart representations of $F$, and your definition would work for this interpretation, but this is not the matrix you have computed. Do you see why showing that the rank of your matrix is $n$ suffices in spite of this technical objection to your definition? Even so, my answer/hint provides a more straightforward way to obtain the result.

Comment: This is actually something I have been thinking about for quite some time. I suspected that I needed to put an appropriate coordinate system on $S^n$ before computing the matrix, this would however lead me to more doubts: what coordinate system should I use? Let's for example say that I pick the stereographic projections $(U_1, \phi_1), (U_2, \phi_2)$ (although it may not be the optimal choice for this particular exercise). Do I then need to compute the jacobian matrix of the coordinate representation in both charts, $\phi_1 \circ \psi$ and $\phi_2 \circ \psi$?

Comment: As for the second part of your comment: are you implying that, irrespective of the coordinate system that we may pick on $S^n$, the rank of the matrix will always be $n$?

Comment: @user3461126 Strictly speaking, the answer is yes, you'd have to compute it for all charts in a given cover by coordinate charts, but for the sphere you'd probably be able to get away with one computation and a symmetry argument. And yes, the rank of the matrix will depend only on the point $p$, regardless of the coordinate chart you use to represent a neighborhood of $\psi(p)$. This follows from the fact that transition maps between coordinate charts are required to be diffeomorphisms, so their jacobians are bijective.

Comment: @user3461126 But, though these caveats are needed in the general case, when $M$ is an open subset of some $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $N$ is an embedded submanifold of some $\mathbb{R}^n$ (this is the case in your problem with $m=n+1$), it also works to consider the jacobian of $F$ as a map $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ without referring to coordinate charts at all, as your computation does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93622/discussion-between-user3461126-and-jawheele).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Given a curve $\gamma : (-1,1) \to S^{n}$, can you find a lift $\tilde{\gamma}:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \backslash\{0\}$ such that $\psi \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$? What does this tell you about $\psi_*$? How does the point $p$ come into play here?

**Edit**: I'll flesh this out to a complete answer. Set $M$=$\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \backslash \{0\}$, $N=S^n$. Recall that the push forward map $\psi_{*p} : T_pM \to T_{\psi(p)}N$ is defined as follows: for any $v \in T_pM$, if $\gamma: (-1,1) \to M$ is a path satisfying $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, then $\psi_{*p}(v)=(\psi \circ \gamma)'(0)$.

Now, if we fix $p \in M$, then for any $v \in T_{\psi(p)}N$ with representative path $\gamma$ in $N$ (so $\gamma(0)=\psi(p) = \frac{p}{\|p\|}$, $\gamma'(0)=v$, and $\|\gamma(t)\|=1$), we may define the path $\tilde{\gamma}$ in $M$ by $\tilde{\gamma}(t)=\|p\| \cdot \gamma(t)$, so that $\psi \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(0)=p$. By definition of the push forward, then,
$$\psi_{*p}(\tilde{\gamma}'(0)) = (\psi \circ \tilde{\gamma})'(0) = \gamma'(0) = v,$$
showing that $\psi_{*p}$ is surjective.

This is an argument that, once you've seen once, you shouldn't need to write out again: it's clear that surjectivity of the pushforward is equivalent to being able to find a lift $\tilde{\gamma}$ through $p$ of any (sufficiently short) path $\gamma$ through $\psi(p)$.

Comment: I've never seen a "lift", nor I know the definition (I just looked it up on Wikipedia) so I don't think that is the way I should try to solve this. Anyway, what I would be able to tell is that $\gamma_* = (\psi \circ \overline{\gamma})_* = \psi_* \circ \overline{\gamma}_*$, right?

Comment: @user3461126 The word "lift" here can be interpreted as just a descriptive word; the definition of what I mean by it is just that $\psi \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$. While what you've written is true, it's not quite what we need to make the conclusion. Instead, it tells you by definition of the push forward map that $\psi_*(\tilde{\gamma}'(t))=\gamma'(t)$ for any $t \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: @user3461126 Now recall that any $v \in T_{\psi(p)} S^n$ can be realized as $\gamma'(0)$ for some choice of $\gamma$ (oftentimes this is practically the definition of the tangent space).

Answer (score 0):

You also can prove this without any calculation. Let $\Phi : S\times R^+ \to \bf R^n$ defined by $\Phi(y,t)=t.y$, and $\tilde \Psi (x)= (\Psi(x),{x\over \vert x \vert}) $so that $\tilde \Psi \circ \tilde \Phi  = Id$ and $\tilde \Phi \circ \Psi = Id$. It follows that $\tilde \Phi$ is a diffeormophism, but the projection $S\times R^+\to S$ is a submersion, and therefore $\Phi = p\circ \tilde \Psi$ is a submersion.